# How do you pass 2-dimensional array of character into a function?

Tags: c, string

So i'm trying to pass

```
char parent[n][50];
```

into a function initialize(); 
And then copy the char x, into the parent [ i ] inside the initialize(); function. Example

```
x = "Cityname"
and when passed into the initialize();
it would do
strcpy(parent[i], x);
to make the
parent[i] = "Cityname"
```

```
void initialize(char *parent, int *ranks, char x, int i){

    strcpy(parent[i], x);
    ranks[i] = '0';

}

int main(){

    int n, i = 1;
    char x[20];

    printf("Enter how many city are there : "); scanf("%d", &n); fflush(stdin);

    char parent[n][20];
    int ranks[n];

    while(1){
        printf("enter city name: "); scanf("%[^\n]", x);
        if(i <= n){
            initialize(parent[][20], ranks, x, i);
            i++;
        } else {
            printf("The city is at maximum\n");
        }
    }
}
```

It tells a warning:

```
passing argument 1 of 'strcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast 
note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'char' 
and also in function main 
error: expected expression before ']' token
```

Can anyone explain how to strcpy(parent[i], x) correctly? I can't seem to figure this problem out.

Comment: initialize wants a char*, often used to represent a 1D array, but parent is a 2D array. initialize should accept parent as char (*parent)[20], or as char parent[][20]

Comment: Array indexes start with 0 not 1. Do: `int i = 0;` and `if (i < n)`

Comment: @Programman What should i do if i want to change the parent in main too, 
```Initialize(&parent, ranks, x, i);``` can't seem to works

Comment: @CraigEstey oh, that's right, thank you

Comment: You should be able to pass initialize(parent, ranks, x, i), and parent will change in main. Because parent is already an array, it can be converted into a pointer without taking the address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several problems with your code. Arrays vs pointers in C can be confusing, so there are a few rules to keep in mind:

char x[n] can be automatically converted by the C compiler to char *x.

char x[10][20] is represented under the hood as a 1D array, and the compiler computes the offsets behind the scenes. For example, if x were a 10 x 20 array, the expression x[1][2] could be compiled as `*(x + 22)`. For this reason, it can cause surprising results to cast a 2D array to a char*, and it is invalid to cast a 2D array to a char**.

With these rules in mind, here is how I would change your code

```
void initialize(char (*parent)[20], int *ranks, char *x, int i){

    strcpy(parent[i], x);
    ranks[i] = '0'; // Did you want an automatic conversion from char to int here? Maybe you meant ranks[i] = 0?

}

int main(){

    int n, i = 0; // As Craig mentions, i should start at 0.
    char x[20];

    printf("Enter how many city are there : "); scanf("%d", &n); fflush(stdin);

    char parent[n][20];
    int ranks[n];

    while(1){
        printf("enter city name: "); scanf("%19s", x); // scanf will automatically stop at whitespace, and you must include the max length to avoid a buffer overrun.
        if(i < n){
            initialize(parent, ranks, x, i);
            i++;
        } else {
            printf("The city is at maximum\n");
            // Maybe break here, unless you want an infinite loop
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hello, thanks for the answers, i really appreciate it. I'm not familiar with ```char (*parent)[20]```, what difference does it makes with ```char parent[ ] [20]``` ?

Comment: These types are very similar, and the compiler will happily convert char parent[][20] to char (*parent)[20]. The technical difference is that char parent[][20] is an array of unknown size, whereas char (*parent)[20] is a pointer to an array. The main observable difference is that it's possible to assign to a pointer using =, but not possible to assign to an array.

Comment: `char (*parent)[20]` and `char parent[ ] [20]` as function parameters are both pointers.  Neither is an array.  There are both a pointer to an array 20 of `char`.  `char parent[][20]` is  not an array of unknown size.  Assigning as in `void initialize2(char parent[][20]){
  parent = 0;
  }` is OK.

Comment: Interesting, so they are actually identical?